# Optimising Charging Station Selection

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

Follow up question to [Optimising EV Charging Station Selection using PuLP in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76067421/optimising-ev-charging-station-selection-using-pulp-in-python/76067770?noredirect=1#comment134165142_76067770)

**Current set-up**

```
from pulp import * 

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
BC = 100 # battery capacity
SOC_in = 1.0 # (%) initial state of charge 
SOC_max = 1.0 #(%) maximum SOC

# energy consumed in each trip segment
e_c = [23.5,  4.6,  4.4, 33.8, 89.5,  0. , 24.5,  4.7, 21.5,  0. ,  0. ,
       16.2,  4.8, 20.1,  0. , 62.8,  0.6, 40.8, 41.1,  5.1, 16.7,  0. ,
       39.6,  9.6,  9.8, 23.7,  0. ,  0. , 23.4,  5.3,  8.6, 23.7, 18.6,
        5.8,  9.1,  0.1,  0. ,  0.1,  0. ,  0.3, 19.8,  0. ,  4.9, 23.4,
        7.7,  9.6,  8. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. , 28.1,  5.5,  9.3,
        0. ,  0.1, 27.9, 41.3,  2.8, 20.8,  6.4,  5.7, 28.4,  7.7, 35.2,
        2.8, 21. , 11.8,  0.1, 21.6,  7.4, 13.5,  8.6,  7.5,  0. , 12.8,
       10.5,  0.4,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5, 37.2,  5.8, 19. , 10.7, 21.7, 17.1,
        0.9,  0. , 17.1, 12. ,  7.9,  2.4,  0.2, 20.6,  4.9, 21.1]

# energy recharged in each trip segment
e_r = [30.7,  64.8,  31.2, 181.2,   2.2,  66.5,  30.3,  52.8,  43.8,
        54.1, 151.1,  33.9,  22.2,  68.3,  66.4,  70.2, 170.5, 260.2,
        32.7,  72.6,  89.1, 138.1,  54.6,  70.2,  24.3,  42.2,  44.4,
        38. ,  38.8,  30.1,  28.7, 179.4,  48.6,  96.6,   0.2,  38.5,
        44.5,   0.4,   0.4,  28.8,  13.5,  25.5,  44.9, 196.8, 269.8,
       215.7,  81.1, 166.6,   0.4,   0.4,   0.1,  22.3, 111.9,  36.9,
        43.3,  38. , 712.2,   9.7,  25.2, 242.3,  24.5,  49.4,  31.6,
       231.6,   0.4,  27.5, 228.6,  31.7, 685.1, 812.4,  84.5,  36.7,
        28.4, 214.7,   0.5,  46. ,  61.3,   0.4,   0.4,  22.4,   0.4,
         0.5,  47.5,  27. ,  43.8, 182.3,  24.2,  76.3,  54. , 748.8,
        72. ,  46. ,  31.3, 113.2,   0.4,  22.7,  70.6,  78.9]

candidate_nodes = range(len(e_c))
n = len(candidate_nodes)


# Define optimization problem
model = LpProblem("EV charging optimization modellem", LpMinimize)

### Decision variables
X = LpVariable.dicts("UseLocation", candidate_nodes, cat=LpBinary)
E = LpVariable.dicts("energy", candidate_nodes, lowBound=0, upBound = 100, cat = LpContinuous)


### Objective function
model += lpSum(X[i] for i in candidate_nodes)

### Constraints

# Initial energy level
model += E[0] == SOC_in * BC  # typo fixed

for i in range(n-1):
    # Energy at next stop (only add charge if charging station is built there)
    model += E[i+1] <= E[i] - e_c[i] + (e_r[i] * X[i])  # less than or equal => prevent over-charge

    # Energy does not exceed battery capacity
    model += E[i+1] <= BC * SOC_max

    # Has enough energy to reach the next stop without going below minimum battery level
    model += E[i] >= e_c[i] 

# Solve
status = model.solve()

# print the "build plan":
build_plan = [i for i in candidate_nodes if X[i].varValue > 0]
print('build at nodes: ')
print(build_plan)

plt.plot(candidate_nodes, [E[i].varValue for i in candidate_nodes], color='r', label='no bonus')
plt.scatter(build_plan, [0 for t in build_plan], s=10, alpha=0.6, color='orange', label='no-bonus charge')

# replace the objective function with this
model += lpSum(X[i] for i in candidate_nodes) - 1/(100*100)*lpSum(E[i] for i in candidate_nodes)
status2 = model.solve()

# QA the build plan has the same NUMBER of build points
build_plan_2 = [i for i in candidate_nodes if X[i].varValue > 0]
assert len(build_plan) == len(build_plan_2)

print('build at nodes: ', build_plan_2)
plt.plot(candidate_nodes, [E[i].varValue for i in candidate_nodes], color='b', label='bonus')
plt.scatter(build_plan_2, [0 for t in build_plan_2], s=10, alpha=0.6, color='g', label='charge')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

The above works. **BUT** Each of the nodes at e_r represents a point where the vehicle has stopped to charge, not necessarily a unique charging station. The following array 'station_labels ' actually contains which charging station the vehicle has stopped at.

```
station_labels = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 4, 5, 4,
       4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3]
```

So the vehicle stops at charging station 0 three times, then goes to charging station 1, then 0 again, etc. etc. You can see from this array that probably stations 0, 1,  and 4 will be necessary for the vehicle to complete its trip while 2, 3, and 5 may not be because the vehicle hardly visits them. (In fact, when you run the optimization as is station 5 is not used, but 2 and 3 are although they might not need to be)

**Goal:** Map the break points to the actual stations they represent in the optimization problem

**Attempted so far:**
I tried changing the decision variable X to just the unique values in station_labels, and then mapping X to the station labels in the constraints by changing the 'Energy at next stop' constraint.

So

```
X = LpVariable.dicts("UseLocation", candidate_nodes, cat=LpBinary)
```

changed to

```
X = LpVariable.dicts("UseLocation", range(len(np.unique(station_labels))), lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpBinary)
```

and

```
model += E[i+1] <= E[i] - e_c[i] + (e_r[i] * X[i])
```

changed to

```
model += E[i+1] <= E[i] - e_c[i] + (e_r[i] * X[station_labels[i]])
```

however this makes the optimization say "problem infeasible" and gives some nonsense output like this:[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: The logic on this ... as extended from the previous question is starting to fall apart a bit.  You are missing an essential piece of information (unless I don't understand the structure of the problem):  Where the heck is the car going relative to the stations?  In the previous, it was assumed the array was the route of travel.  Now?  It is like me showing you a map of the state and asking where should I stop for gas?  You'd first need to know the intended route of travel.  Why would the vehicle go to station 0 three times in a row?  why go back to station 0 after 1?

Comment: Also, how do you know `e_r` a priori?  How would you know how much charge the vehicle can or will take at a station?  Why wouldn't it just fill up or fill to some set level?  It seems this should be a **variable** and not a known value as you now describe this model

Comment: @AirSquid Thanks for the clarifying questions. In response to the first -- the station labels indicate the route of travel in that they contain the order in which the stations were visited. The vehicle goes to station 0 three times in a row because it is a taxi, and it is making loops.

Comment: In response to the second question, e_r represents the maximum energy the vehicle can charge at that node. It is calculated given the amount of time the vehicle spends at the node and the charging rate (minus charger coupling and decoupling time).

Comment: Another way I'm trying is adjusting the first constraint to be two constraints in the following way (may make more sense to you):

    # Time spent charging at stop (only if charger built there)
    model += T[i] <= X[i] * dt[i]

    # Energy at next stop
    model += E[i+1] == E[i] - e_c[i] + (T[i] * charge_rate)/3.6e3 # convert to hours from seconds

Comment: where T is defined as:
T = LpVariable.dicts("TimeCharging", range(num_stops), lowBound=0, upBound=dt[i], cat=LpContinuous)